# Which side of the baking paper should face up?

Tags: baking

My baking paper has two sides: one waxy looking silky-feeling side, and one clean looking side with more friction when you run your finger over it.

Which side should face up against the food?  I've had the paper stick to pizza several times & I keep forgetting to check which side causes it.

Comment: Hmm, I have never noticed a difference. What brand do you use?

Comment: Bunsgaard _____

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Baking paper has a silicone coating to prevent sticking. If yours is only coated on one side (the waxy side), this side should touch the food.

Comment: Yep that's what I did, normally it works ok but Tesco's one sticks like mad when using the waxy side up. I think it really does come down to who makes it.